# Hibernate's SQLQuery executeUpdate function starts, but does not fully execute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Working on a Spring application that uses Hibernate, and in my DAO layer we are running an UPDATE statement to update some values in an Oracle database.

To make sure I'm not crazy, I ran the statement in SQL Developer to make sure it works properly. Here is part of my DAO code:

```
public void updateObjectInMyTable(SomeClassA objectOfSomeClassA) {
        Session session = getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "UPDATE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_XYZ SET FIRST_NAME=:firstName, LAST_NAME=:lastName, ADDRESS=:address, CITY=:city, ZIPCODE=:zipcode WHERE ID_NUMBER = :idNumber";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("firstName", objectOfSomeClassA.getFirstName());
        query.setParameter("lastName", objectOfSomeClassA.getLastName());
        query.setParameter("address", objectOfSomeClassA.getAddress());
        query.setParameter("city", objectOfSomeClassA.getCity());
        query.setParameter("zipcode", objectOfSomeClassA.getZipcode());
        query.setParameter("idNumber", objectOfSomeClassA.getIdNumber());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

(Excuse the poor variables names used for substitutions of the real ones.) I did debug on the server and I do not see any errors with `query.executeUpdate()` **It gets to that line, and doesn't pass on to the next statement I have in my service layer.**

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may have an uncommitted transaction that is holding a lock that this transaction requires. In development environments, this is often due to a developer transaction in SQL Developer. Use the Oracle tools to see what lock your update is waiting for an who is holding the lock.

Comment: @Rob Thanks Rob, you were correct. Checked and I had a couple of transactions open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your transaction ?!

**Use :**

```
session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

add this in the end line of your code.

I hope this helps you.